# Quote source for St. Leopold Mandić on Continual Prayer

Tags: catholicism, prayer, reference-request

In many places, [here](https://www.translationdirectory.com/sense_of_life/article_en_0630.php) for example, I have seen (pretty much verbatim):

> Father Leopold often said that whatever we do on earth, we should do it in the presence of God, then our whole life will be a constant prayer.

QUESTION: Does anyone know of an online site, or perhaps a book, which puts forth the *actual quote* of [St. Leopold Maria Mandić, OFMCap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Mandi%C4%87), which is only indirectly attributed to St. Leopold above?

Comment: This [short biography](https://www.translationdirectory.com/sense_of_life/article_en_0630.php) may point to some of his extant writings: "The saint did not leave us any autobiography, but his private correspondence, his brief notes on pictures and stories of his confreres indicate that coming to terms with the impossibility of missionary work was not easy for him. "